# How do I troubleshoot my Postgres installation?

Tags: macos, postgresql, heroku

While trying to install Postgres I inadvertently installed multiple versions of Postgres. The environment is a total mess. It seems like there is reminisce of the different installation all over the place. I'm having a hard time to get anything to work. I originally attempted to install postgres from the postgres website and switched to the Heroku postgres app. I don't believe I have the binaries installed correctly and I can't make any references to binaries to the path since they don't exist.

So considering I'm a pretty Junior dev, I don't know which direction to take this trouble shooting.. I'm looking for ideas or help. What should I be looking at next? (Can't upload screenshots because I don't have enough points, here's a dump)

```
Shamiuls-MacBook-Pro:/ shammowla$ which psql
Shamiuls-MacBook-Pro:/ shammowla$ cd Applications/Postgres.app/
Shamiuls-MacBook-Pro:Postgres.app shammowla$ ls
Contents
Shamiuls-MacBook-Pro:Postgres.app shammowla$ cd Contents
Shamiuls-MacBook-Pro:Contents shammowla$ ls
Info.plist      MacOS           ResourceRules.plist Versions        _CodeSignature
Library         PkgInfo         Resources       XPCServices
Shamiuls-MacBook-Pro:Contents shammowla$ cd MacOS
```

Also I have MySql installed on my machine.

Appreciate any help I can get!

Comment: Can someone please help me figure this out.. Still stuck

Answer (score 0):

Probably the first thing is to remove the PostgreSQL Application from your machine

Look then to install homebrew, and install PostgreSQL from there via 'brew install postgresql'

This will link the most current version (9.3) into your /usr/local directory structure

You said you had multiple versions installed, how did you install them ??